# Proof explanation of Dilworth's theorem.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, order-theory

I am reading the proof of Dilworth's theorem which uses induction.I have several doubts regarding the proof and I am looking for explanation.I first tried to resolve those doubts on my own but it seems to be too much difficult without any help as my brain is not so *combinatorial*.I state the theorem below and give the proof which I read.I will mention where I have doubts.

**Theorem(Dilworth,1950)**

Let $P$ be a finite poset.Then the maximum size of an antichain in $P$ is equal to the minimum size of a cover of $P$ by disjoint chains.

*Proof:* Let $M$ and $m$ denote respectively the maximum size of an antichain in $P$ and minimum size of a cover of $P$ by disjoint chains.

It is trivial that $m\geq M$.

Now we will show that $m\leq M$.We proceed by induction on $|P|$.

For $|P|=1$ ,it is trivial as both the sizes are $1$.

Now assume that the result is true for $k<|P|$.

Now,we prove the result for $k=|P|$.

Let $C$ be a maximal chain in $P$.

*Case-1:* Every antichain in $P\setminus C$ contains at most $M-1$ elements.

So,$P\setminus C$ is a union of $\leq M-1$ disjoint chains by induction hypothesis.

$\implies$ $P$ is a union of $\leq M$ disjoint chains.

So,$m\leq M$.

*Case-2:*

Assume that $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_M\}=A$ is an antichain in $P\setminus C$.

Define $S^-=\{x\in P:x\leq a_i \text{ for some } i \}$

$S^+=\{x\in P:x\geq a_i \text{ for some } i \}$

Therefore $A\subset S^-$

Because of maximality,the largest element in $C$ is not in $S^-$

So,$|S^-|<|P|$
By induction hypothesis, $S^-$ is the union of $M$ disjoint chains $S_1^-,S_2^-,...,S_M^-$ where $a_i\in S_i^-$ $\color{red}{\text{(Why?)}}$

If $x\in S_i^-$ and $x>a_i$ then since $x\leq a_j$ for some $j$ we would get $a_i<a_j$ which is a contradiction.

Therefore $a_i$ is the maximal element of $S_i^-$ for all $i=1(1)M$

Do,the same for $S^+=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^M S_i^+$ where $S_i^+\cap S_j^+=\phi$ for all $i\neq j$ and $a_i\in S_i^+$ such that $a_i$ is the minimal element of $S_i^+$

$D_i=S_i^+\cup S_i^-$ is a chain for $i=1(1)M$ observing that $P=S^+\cup S^-$ is the union of disjoint chains $D_i$ where $i=1(1)M$

This is from a note given by our instructor.Can someone explain me the proof so that it becomes crystal clear?Concrete examples at critical points is also welcome.

**Addendum**

*I have tried to provide as much I have understood below.*

Clearly,$m\geq M$ because if $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_M\}$ is a maximal antichain and $P=A_1\cup A_2\cup...\cup A_m$ is a cover of $P$ by disjoint chains,then no two $a_i$'s are in the same $A_k$ so,at least $M$ disjoint chains are required.

Now,we have to show,$m\leq M$.

Now to understand *Case:1* let us consider the following example:

Let,$X=\{1,2,3\}$ and $P=\mathcal P(X)$.Notice that $M=3$ here.

Now,$C=\{\phi,\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$

Then,$P\setminus C=\{\{2\},\{3\},\{2,3\},\{3,1\}\}$

Antichains in $P\setminus C$ are $\{\{2\},\{3\}\}$ and $\{\{2,3\},\{3,1\}\},\{\{2\},\{3,1\}\}$.

So,we observe that all antichains in $P\setminus C$ contains $\leq 3-1=2$ elements and hence we are in *Case:1*.

Now,clearly we obtain that $P$ is a union of at most $3$ disjoint chains.So,$m\leq 3=M$.

Now let us come to *Case:2* which says that there is an antichain in $P\setminus C$ of size $M$.

Assume that $A=\{a_1,...,a_M\}$ is an antichain in $P\setminus C$.

Let, $S^-=\{x\in P:x\leq a_i$ for some $i\}$

Then,$A\subset S^-$.The explanation is given below:

> $x\in A\implies x=a_i\leq a_i$ for some $i\implies x \in S^-$

Now,$C$ is a finite chain and hence it has a largest element say $a$.

Due to maximality of size of $C=\{...,a\}$,$a\notin S^-$.

> If $a\in S^-\implies a\leq a_i$ for some $i\implies C\cup \{a_i\}$ is larger chain in size that $C$.

So,$|S^-|<|P|$.

So,we can use the induction hypothesis.

$S^-=S_1^-\cup...\cup S_M^-$ disjoint chains $\color{red}{\text{(Why $M$ chains?It could have been any number $k\geq M$,so why $k>M$ is not possible?)}}$

Where $a_i\in S_i$ .

> Because for $i\neq j$, $a_i,a_j$ both cannot be in $S_i$ together or in $S_j$ together.

Now,$a_i$ is (the) maximal element of $S_i^-$.

> Because if $x\in S_i^-$ and $x>a_i$ Then since $x\in S_i^-\subset S^-\implies x\leq a_j$ and so,$a_i<a_j$ which is a contradiction.

Doing the same for $S^+$ we can show that $a_i$ is the minimal element of $S_i^+$.

So,$D_i=S_i^-\cup S_i^+=\{....\leq a_i\leq...\}$ is a chain.

For $i\neq j$, $D_i\cap D_j=\phi$.$\color{red}{\text{(Why?)}}$

So, $P=S^+\cup S^-=D_1\cup...\cup D_M$ which is a union of $M$ disjoint chains.

So,$m\leq M$.

Comment: I think I got the answer to the question that why should $m\geq M$.This is perhaps because if $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_M\}$ is a maximal antichain then consider chains $A_i$ containing $a_i$ and covering $P$,then $A_i$ contains no other $a_j$.So,we can cover $P$ by $M$ number of disjoint chains.But if the number becomes less that $M$,then at least one $A_i$ contains $a_j$ such that $j\neq i$ but $a_i$ and $a_j$ cannot be in the same chain as they are not comparable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have understood the most part of the proof pretty well.

---

> By induction hypothesis, $S^-$ is the union of $M$ disjoint chains ... $\color{red}{\text{(Why?)}}$

What is the induction hypothesis? It is the assumption that the result (i.e., Dilworth's theorem) is true for every poset $Q$ such that $\color{red}{|Q|<k}$. More specifically, if a poset $|Q|<k$, then the maximum size of an antichain in $Q$ is equal to the minimum size of a cover of $Q$ by disjoint chains.

Since $|S^-|<|P|=k$, by the induction hypothesis, the maximum size of an antichain in $S^-$ is equal to the minimum size of a cover of $S^-$ by disjoint chains.

Since $S^-\subset P$, the maximum size of an antichain in $S^-$ is $\le$ the maximum size of an antichain in $P$, which is $M$.
On the other hand, the maximum size of an antichain in $S^-$ is $\ge M$, the size of antichain $A\subset S^-$.
Hence, the maximum size of an antichain in $S^-$ is $M$.

Hence, $M$ is equal to the minimum size of a cover of $S^-$ by disjoint chains. That is, $S^-$ is a union of $M$ disjoint chains.

---

> For $i\neq j$, $D_i\cap D_j=\phi$. $\color{red}{\text{(Why?)}}$

$D_i=S_i^-\cup S_i^+$
$D_j=S_j^-\cup S_j^+$

For the sake of contradiction, suppose $c\in D_i\cap D_j$. Since $c\in D_i$, there are two cases.

- $c\in S_i^-$.
  Since $S_i^-$ and $S_j^-$ are disjoint, $c\in S_j^+$.
  By definition of $S_i^-$, $c\le a_i$.
  By definition of $S_j^+$, $c\ge a_j$.
  Hence $a_j\le c \le a_i$, which says $a_i$ and $a_j$ are comparable. A contradiction.
- $c\in S_i^+$.
  Since $S_i^+$ and $S_j^+$ are disjoint, $c\in S_j^-$.
  By definition of $S_i^+$, $c\ge a_i$.
  By definition of $S_j^-$, $c\le a_j$.
  Hence $a_i\le c \le a_j$, which says $a_i$ and $a_j$ are comparable. A contradiction.

Hence, there is no such $c$. So $D_i\cap D_j=\emptyset$

In fact, it is unnecessary to prove $D_i\cap D_j=\emptyset$. If $P$ is a union of $M$ chains, $P$ is also a union of $M$ or less disjoint chains, since we can keep removing any shared element from one of the sharing pair until there is no intersecting pair. In other words, the minimum size of a cover of $P$ by disjoint chains is the same as the minimum size of a cover of $P$ by chains.